# Memory leak occurring in iPhone X after updating to iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, memory-leaks, iphone-x

As soon as I updated to iOS 13 in my iPhone X memory leaks started occurring and memory consumptions keeps on increasing never comes down. Its not happening with other devices such as iPhone 6,7 etc have verified with that as well.

I have tried debugging leak with instruments which shown the following leak diagram

[image: Memory leak flow diagram]

Comment: @MohmmadS I did not get your point? Can you explain

Comment: if you continue with the application flow does those leak number increase ? or decrease

Comment: There is only one leak happening and its eating up the entire phone ram memory and app getting crashed

Comment: are you able to spot what line or what it is in general ?

Comment: @MohmmadS We are not able to spot the line of code

Comment: it's a urlSession memory leak, now sometimes this happens, could you post some code ? in a suspected URLSession you wrote around the scene causing this issue ?

Comment: Same type of leaks happen in iOS 12 for me..iPhone 8

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple `URLSession` objects listed here. That suggests that those sessions were instantiated, but never released. This can happen easily when using the delegate-based `URLSession` API.

If you’re going to create a separate session for each request, make sure to call `finishTasksAndInvalidate` after submitting the request, so that the `URLSession` can clean up after itself.

For example, the following ...

```
func start() {
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

    session.dataTask(with: url).resume()
}
```

... results in:

[image]

However, it is resolved if we add a `finishTasksAndInvalidate`:

```
func start() {
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

    session.dataTask(with: url).resume()

    session.finishTasksAndInvalidate()
}
```

Or alternatively, instantiate a single `URLSession` (or use `URLSession.shared`) and then all of the requests can share the same session.